# Is there a way to preserve the format of an stdout output and transport it to a file?

Tags: c, file, stdout

With your help, with the help of this community, I managed to get a working code for printing 2 more elements of an array in each row... Thanks to @Ted Lyngmo.
I would like to know, if there exists any way with which I could easily transport the stdout format to an external file...
This below works neatly for stdout...
And if there isn't an easy way, how can this be optimalised for external file writing?

**Currently an external output file puts all the content in one long line, I want to avoid that happening**... Thank you for your ideas.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp=fopen("test.txt","w");
    printf("Number of rows: ");

    int num;
    if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) return 1;

    // row starts at 0 and ends at num-1
    // columns start with 2 and increases by 2 for every row
    for (int row = 0, columns = 2, value = num; row < num; ++row, columns += 2) {
        // and value increases by `num` every time it's been printed:
        for (int c = 0; c < columns; ++c, value += num) {
            fprintf(fp, "%d ", value);
            printf("%d ", value);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

In stdout I get what I expect... [stdout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcR0M.png)
In Notepad++ or in wordpad I get the long line. [external file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KYJx.png)

Comment: it shouldn't print out in a long line, unless you're opening the file in binary mode and uses Notepad on very old Windows, because in text mode `\n` would be translated to the correct new line sequence on the platform, and new Notepad can recognized LF or CR files without problem

Comment: Thank you very much... this was indeed what I wanted to know... I'll keep this in mind

Answer (score 0):

Use `fopen` to open a file for writing, then use `fprintf` instead of `printf` to allow you to specify the file to write to.

To open the file "outfile.txt" for writing:

```
FILE *outfile = fopen("outfile.txt", "w");
```

Then to write to the file:

```
fprintf(outfile, "%d ", value);
```

In both places:

```
fprintf(outfile, "\n");
```

And be sure to close the file when you're done:

```
fclose(outfile);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response... I clarify, I want the output file to keep the same format the output does in stdout... When I write it to a file, it just prints it all in one long line, I want to avoid that happening...

Comment: @askingforhelp that's the issue in your file opening part which you didn't show. You need to create a [mcve]. Your code works the same in either file or stdout because they're both streams

Comment: You are right@phuclv, sorry for the inconvenience.  I edited the post accordingly...

Comment: @askingforhelp You need to switch from `printf` to `fprintf` for *each* call that does the printing you want.  See my edit.

Comment: @askingforhelp you can also just use the shell redirection (`./your_command > file`) instead of rewriting your code to write to file. If you want to write to both destinations then use `tee`